# Slowing down recorded mouse and click

Tags: autoit, autoit-recorder

I'm using AutoIt Recorder to record all my clicks, but it re-plays too fast. How can I slow it down?

I can use `sleep()`, but I don't want to put it after every line.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18199297/4157124).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
autoItSetOption("MouseClickDelay", 10) ;10 milliseconds
```

Where 10ms are the default. So increase it slowly. For more have a look at:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AutoItSetOption.htm